# How to reconcile ENUM / option values in relational SQL with accepted PHP values without having to maintain identical value lists in both places?

Tags: php, mysql, enums, schema

I am designing a simple PHP form interface for a website and I wish to normalize all the dropdown fields. To that end, I've scrapped the draft database schema which had a single table for the entire entry form (with ENUM values for `<option>` input) and adopted a normalized table schema.

I thought this would be simple, but it's not.

The server-side application uses the resulting POST values to regenerate the form on-submit because certain dropdown values do not coincide with database values, but instead trigger actions or user errors. (these invalid entries are prevented with javascript but still have to be validated.)

So the PHP has to know what the names and the POST values mean.

The javascript/html itself generated by PHP has to have the same info for the same reason, but should not use the actual database index of each `<option>`, unless it's something simple like 1-5. (I assume) Instead I was going to give each option a shorthand string value that is shared by the JS & PHP, translated into a SQL numeric value/index by a constant array.

This can be supplied by the same PHP element that controls acceptable values; but the "public" values have to have some common meaning in case either code is edited, and the private indices of each field name / value tuple are meaningless without access to a meaningful static flag value.

I've been told not to use "magic numbers" by various articles I've read. I can't use the same flags for all the values (boolean or bitwise) because I assume they'd be in one big table for all the different dropdowns with a  numeric/string `value` column and a string `name` column.

A separate table for each dropdown doesn't seem to help things any, unless a specific dropdown has extensive logic attached to it, which one does. (I've separated it out). If there were only one dropdown item, the same problem exists: both the DB and the app have a list of each value set and what they mean.

If the MySQL controls the order the accepted values appear in, the PHP still has to know which one is which. If the MySQL stores all the values and generic names for the dropdown fields, that still requires the PHP to know what order they go in (which is subject to change). And replace the default (meaningful? canonical?) `value` for `option_id` with an actual (descriptive) text description in the dropdown (which is subject to change).

This requires the PHP to know in advance what the values mean, rendering the relational table worthless except for DB-side validation (which steps on server validation and potentially destroys the integrity of the database if the app logic changes) that amounts to a fancier version of simply using ENUM.

What is the DRY method for doing this (MySQL / PHP)?

Should I simply use ENUM and let PHP keep track of what each ENUM values mean?

Should I use an INT field instead of ENUM and let the PHP determine what the numbers mean?

Comment: I'm specifically wondering if there's 1) a way to normalize this without having to keep a duplicate record of each value in the PHP application (and the resulting relational table index to boot as a result); should the php determine allowable MySQL values or vice versa; and if the PHP determines validity of the option values, what's the point of having the database control for a set of values at all? Maybe I should just have the application pull all values for a given select statement as string and treat unrecognized values as a disabled default selected value?

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding info on this... most Q&A's related to this issue online are bone-simple how-to's on how to populate dropdowns with ENUM fields, etc. What I'm wondering is how to populate dropdowns if the MySQL is the sole source of data in a relational table; and whether to do so *at all* if the PHP has to keep track of each option. Is it even worth using an ENUM if the PHP has to validate input or should I just use an INT field for every dropdown and let the PHP tell you what the numbers mean? That would be DRY thing to do, but then the data would be non-self-explanatory.